# Swift localizedStringWithFormat number output instead of Text

Tags: ios, swift, localization

Currently I am working on a Localization for my App. When I want to logout the user, I want to tell his name in the alert. So I used the following code:

```
let name = "Matthias Kremer"
let formatedString =  NSLocalizedString("logoutTitleWithName", comment: " abmelden?")
print( String.localizedStringWithFormat(formatedString, name))
```

The Localizable.string file looks like that:

```
"logoutTitleWithName" = "%d abmelden";
```

I supposed to get the following outlet:

> Matthias Kremer abmelden

But instead it is

> 281,600 abmelden

It seams like the String is converted in a Number somehow. Does anybody knows how to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
"logoutTitleWithName" = "%@ abmelden";
```

**%d** is a repacement for decimal value while **%@** for a string